# My app with 3 servlet runs fine on Tomcat but displays 404 error when I try to run it as a container in Docker

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, servlets

Structure of project and Docker file I tried :

[image]

I have an app with 3 servlets that is running fine from tomcat when I start it from IDEA but I have trouble making it run as a docker container. The container runs successfully but then it displays 404 error. What changes do I need to make to the dockerfile?

Comment: Please do not post images of code, as it is impossible for people using screenreaders to help.  Besides, it seems your problem is that you missed the `/` before `usr` in your `COPY` command, so the WAR file gets copied somewhere else.

Comment: Ohhh terribly sorry I will keep your suggestion in mind. I will try you fix and update

Comment: Thank you very very much it had another error that said I was using a newer version of Java but fixed it by changing 
FROM tomcat:<latest> to 
FROM tomcat:9.0.41-jdk15-openjdk

and now it runs perfectly

Comment: @LukeWoodward Can you put your comment as an answer to flag it as such?

Comment: I can do if you post your Dockerfile as text rather than as an image.